# Animate amplitude of sound in a CustomView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

At the moment I want to create an application which can record sound from the microphone and visualize it in a CustomView [like this](https://youtu.be/0BiMLtk5_D8?t=3m). The recording works great and I also get the amplitude of the recorded sound so I can draw the rectangles on the screen withthis code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int h = getMeasuredHeight();

    for(int i=0; i < soundData.size(); i++)
    {
        double data = soundData.get(i);
        canvas.drawRect(15 + 8 * i, (int) (h - data), 21 + 8 * i, h, paint);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't look very nice because the rectangles appear from nowhere. In the video above a nice animation is used to draw the amplitudes on the screen. How can I implement something like this in my CustomView? Which animation type do I have to use and how do I have to draw it then?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create the animation for my own. Here is the [View](https://github.com/Cilenco/AndroidCodeSnippets/blob/master/AudioVisualizer.java) which creates a nice animation for the amplitudes. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this - reviews and ideas are gladly desired.